# Google Foobar Question - Please Pass The Coded Message

Tags: python

Google Foobar Question:

## Please Pass the Coded Messages

You need to pass a message to the bunny prisoners, but to avoid detection, the code you agreed to use is... obscure, to say the least. The bunnies are given food on standard-issue prison plates that are stamped with the numbers 0-9 for easier sorting, and you need to combine sets of plates to create the numbers in the code. The signal that a number is part of the code is that it is divisible by 3. You can do smaller numbers like 15 and 45 easily, but bigger numbers like 144 and 414 are a little trickier. Write a program to help yourself quickly create large numbers for use in the code, given a limited number of plates to work with.

You have L, a list containing some digits (0 to 9). Write a function answer(L) which finds the largest number that can be made from some or all of these digits and is divisible by 3. If it is not possible to make such a number, return 0 as the answer. L will contain anywhere from 1 to 9 digits.  The same digit may appear multiple times in the list, but each element in the list may only be used once.

## Languages

To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py
To provide a Java solution, edit solution.java

## Test cases

Inputs:
    (int list) l = [3, 1, 4, 1]
Output:
    (int) 4311

Inputs:
    (int list) l = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]
Output:
    (int) 94311

Use verify [file] to test your solution and see how it does. When you are finished editing your code, use submit [file] to submit your answer. If your solution passes the test cases, it will be removed from your home folder.

---

So that's the question, my python code only passes 3 out of 5 tests cases. I spent a few hours but can't find out what cases I am missing. Here is my code:

```
maximum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0]
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    global maximum
    s = sum(partial)

    if s%3 == 0:

        if s != 0:
            str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in partial)
            y = int(str1)
            str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in maximum)
            z = int(str1)
            if y>z:
                maximum = partial
              #  print maximum

    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])

def answer(l):
    global maximum
    #maximum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    subset_sum(l,sum(l))
    maximum = sorted(maximum, key=int, reverse=True)
    str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in maximum)
    y = int(str1)

    return y

print(answer([3,1,4,1,5,9]))
```

So what test cases am I not accounting for, and how could I improve it?

Comment: _my python code only passes 3 out of 5 tests cases_ Do you know what the 5 test cases are, and do you know which two are failing?  Does your program produce correct output for the test case given in the instructions?  (input `[3,1,4,1,5,9]` returns `94311`).

Comment: It's been a few years, but I recall not having access to all the test cases. For some of the problems, the test cases were gigantic too. Performance became an issue.

Comment: No, It doesn't say what the tests cases are. Also, the maximum size of the numbers can be 9 digits long, and my code can do those.

Answer (score 1):

try this using combination it may help:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def answer(nums):
    nums.sort(reverse = True)
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(nums) + 1)):
        for tup in combinations(nums, i):
            if sum(tup) % 3 == 0: return int(''.join(map(str, tup)))
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution looks something like this:

1. Arrange the input digits into a single number, in order from largest to smallest.  (The specific digit order won't affect its divisibility by 3.)
2. If this number is divisible by 3, you're done.
3. Otherwise, try removing the smallest digit.  If this results in a number that is divisible by 3, you're done.  Otherwise start over with the original number and try removing the second-smallest digit.  Repeat.
4. Otherwise, try removing digits two at a time, starting with the two smallest.  If any of these result in a number that is divisible by 3, you're done.
5. Otherwise, try removing three digits...
6. Four digits...
7. Etc.
8. If nothing worked, return zero.

Comment: As a fun bit of trivia, you never need to remove more than 2 digits for this problem, even if repeats are allowed. The only way 0 is an answer is if there are 2 or fewer non-zero digits and they are both in the set `{1,4,7}` or both in the set `{2,5,8}`.

Answer (score 0):

Presently, you are forming a number by using adjacent digits only while the question does not say so.
A quick fix would be to set remaining list properly -

```
remaining = numbers[:i] + numbers[i+1:]
```

But you need to think of better algorithm.

**Update**

```
inputNumbers = [2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 5, 7, 9, 3]

inputNumSorted = sorted(inputNumbers)
sumMax = sum(inputNumbers)
queue = [(sumMax, inputNumSorted)]

found = False
while (len(queue) > 0):
    (sumCurrent, digitList) = queue.pop()
    remainder = sumCurrent%3

    if (remainder == 0):
        found = True
        break
    else :
        for index, aNum in enumerate(digitList):
            if(aNum%3 == remainder):
                sumCurrent -= remainder
                digitList.remove(aNum)
                found = True
                break
            else:
                newList = digitList[:index]+digitList[index+1:]
                if (len(newList) > 0):
                    queue.insert(0, (sumCurrent-aNum, newList))
    if(found):
        break

maxNum = 0
if (found):
    for x,y in enumerate(digitList):
        maxNum += (10**x)*y

print(maxNum)
```

Comment: I don't understand where to place that?

Comment: The problem with that is that it takes too long to run it for bigger values

Comment: Yes. I mentioned that. I am updating answer with an iterative version. I don't have access to foobar to test it. Let me know if this is any helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is a complete rewrite of my code. Could you get my code to work, without rewriting the entire thing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the actual solution and this passes in all the test cases

```
import itertools

def solution(l):
    l.sort(reverse = True)
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(l) + 1)):
        for j in itertools.combinations(l, i):
        if sum(tup) % 3 == 0: return int(''.join(map(str, j)))
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a commented solution (that passed all test cases):

```py
def solution(l):
    # sort in decending order
    l = sorted(l, reverse = True)
    # if the number is already divisible by three
    if sum(l) % 3 == 0:
        # return the number
        return int("".join(str(n) for n in l))
    possibilities = [0]
    # try every combination of removing a single digit
    for i in range(len(l)):
        # copy list of digits
        _temp = l[:]
        # remove a digit
        del _temp[len(_temp) - i - 1]
        # check if it is divisible by three
        if sum(_temp) % 3 == 0:
            # if so, this is our solution (the digits are removed in order)
            return int("".join(str(n) for n in _temp))
        # try every combination of removing a second digit
        for j in range(1, len(_temp)):
            # copy list of digits again
            _temp2 = _temp[:]
            # remove another digit
            del _temp2[len(_temp2) - j - 1]
            # check if this combination is divisible by three
            if sum(_temp2) % 3 == 0:
                # if so, append it to the list of possibilities
                possibilities.append(int("".join(str(n) for n in _temp2)))
    # return the largest solution
    return max(possibilities)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from itertools import combinations

def solution(L):
    # Sort the digits in non-increasing order
    L.sort(reverse=True)
    
    # Calculate the sum of the digits
    sum_of_list = sum(L)
   
    if sum_of_list % 3 == 0:
        # Convert the list of digits to an integer
        num = int(''.join(str(x) for x in L))
        return num
    else:
        # Try removing one digit at a time and check if the new list is divisible by 3
        max_num = 0
        for i in range(len(L)):
            test_list = L[:i] + L[i+1:]
            test_sum = sum(test_list)
            if test_sum % 3 == 0:
                num = int(''.join(str(x) for x in test_list))
                if num > max_num:
                    max_num = num
        if max_num > 0:
            return max_num
        
        # If no single-digit removal produces a divisible list, try removing two digits
        def find_largest_divisible(nums):
            nums.sort(reverse=True)
            for i in reversed(range(1, len(nums) + 1)):
                for tup in combinations(nums, i):
                    if sum(tup) % 3 == 0:
                        return int(''.join(map(str, tup)))
            return 0
        num = find_largest_divisible(L)
        if num > 0:
            return num
        
        # If no divisible number is found, return 0
        return 0
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried a lot but test case 3 fails .Sorry for bad variable names

```
import itertools
def solution(l):
    a=[]
    k=''
    aa=0
    b=[]
    for i in range(len(l)+1):
        for j in itertools.combinations(l,i):
            a.append(j)
    for i in a:
        if sum(i)>=aa and sum(i)%3==0 and len(b)<len(i):
            aa=sum(i)
            b=i[::-1]
        else:
            pass
    b=sorted(b)[::-1]
    for i in b:
        k+=str(i)
    if list(k)==[]:
        return 0
    else:
        return k
```

Comment: But if case 3 fails, why did you post it as a solution?

Comment: Because I wanted to help btw I did found the correct solution should I share it?

Comment: Yes, edit this answer to provide the correct solution